# Detect if a String is made of only one kind of character

Tags: java, string, character

I'd like to know if a `String` is made of a repetition of only one type of character.

For example I'd like to detect if a `String` is made of only "b" so it'd be the case for "bb", "bbbb", "bbbbbbbbbbb",...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a regular expression?

```
String pattern = "([a-zA-Z])\\1*";

if (string.matches(pattern)) {
    // The string contains is made up of the same character...

}
```

Comment: But this fails with, for instance, "11111".

Comment: Then change it from `a-zA-z` to something else. It's not an end all solution, he can tailor it to his specifications if he wants.

Comment: Would someone like to tell me why they down-voted me? If I'm wrong, I would like to know why.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one thing still missing is that you need to anchor the pattern at both ends. And perhaps you need a `+` instead of a `*`.

Comment: You're right about the anchor, but I'm right about the *.

Comment: Whether it should be `*` or `+` depends on how empty strings should be treated, which OP did not specify.

Comment: Using + would reject single character strings. Matches doesn't need an anchor, it always tries to match the whole string.

Comment: @fgb Yea, it doesn't look like it needs the anchor. However, the issue about whether to use `+` or `*` depends entirely on whether the OP wants to match single character strings, which he did not clearly specify. Cthulhu's implementation assumed that he did not, and mine assumed that he did.

Comment: @fgb - Perhaps single-character strings should be rejected; there's no repetition. Good point about `String.match` always trying to match the entire string; I was thinking about how matching works in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Using **[Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)**

Something using **backreferences**

```
 boolean b = Pattern.matches("^(.)\\1+$", "aaaaaaa");
 //true

 b = Pattern.matches("^(.)\\1+$", "aaaabbbbaaa");
 //false
```

If you want to match a **1-character** string as well, change the `+` in the Regex to a `*`.

Comment: Don't you need to anchor the pattern at the beginning and end?

Comment: `^...$` you mean? I'm not sure if I've done even this right

Comment: When you use back references, you need to group exactly what you're referencing. See my solution below.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Although you also need to create a capture group for the `\1` to work.

Comment: Thats what I was missing. Corrected.

Comment: I think it still might be wrong. Wouldn't you not catch cases that are only one character long?

Comment: Change the `+` to a `*` and you should be good.

Comment: @Michael Nice catch. This seems surprisingly hard to get right using regex.

Comment: The OP wants to detect 2 or more `b`s in his question-example. That's why I left the `+` in and not the `*`.

Comment: This has been fun. Thanks @Michael and Ted :)

Comment: I'm relatively new to back-references too so working on this problem with you both has definitely helped me too!

Answer (score 1):

Get the first character of the string and compare it with the remaining, if it does not change the string has only one type of character (this solution does work for non-BMP unicode).

```
public boolean sameCaracterInString(String string){
     if(string == null || string.isEmpty()) 
       return false;
 
    for(int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++)
       if(string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(0))
          return false;
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "^" + str.charAt(0) + "+$"
return str.replaceAll(regex,"").length() == 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: What if str begins with a regex meta character?

Comment: This is cunning idea to avoid backreferences, but it doesn't work because you can't rely on charAt working the way you expect outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane.  Consider these ```System.err.println("a".equals(String.valueOf("a".charAt(0))));``` and ```System.err.println("".equals(String.valueOf("".charAt(0))));```  The first returns true, but the second returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static Pattern ONE_CHAR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");
public static boolean isOneChar(String str) {
    return ONE_CHAR_PATTERN.matcher(str).matches();
}
```

I came up with a number of other ways of doing this, but using regexes (as above) is the only easy way I can come up with that deals correctly with characters outside the unicode Basic Multilingual Plane, e.g

```
System.err.println(isOneChar(""));
```

When dealing with characters outside of the BMP, you can't rely on charAt or length on strings to return the character or the number of characters.

Here's what dreamcrashes' answer might look like if it dealt correctly with unicode:

```
public static boolean isOneChar(String string) {
    if(string == null || string.isEmpty()) return false; // probably, could also make an argument for empty being true.
    int startCodePoint = Character.codePointAt(string, 0);
    int length = string.length();
    int position = Character.charCount(startCodePoint);
    while (position < length) {
        int thisCodePoint = Character.codePointAt(string, position);
        if (thisCodePoint != startCodePoint) return false;
        position += Character.charCount(thisCodePoint);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's another possibility, based on the replacement idea suggested by Satyajit:

```
public static boolean isOneChar(String string) {
    String firstCharacter = string.substring(0, string.offsetByCodePoints(0, 1));
    return string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(firstCharacter), "").length() == 0;
}
```

I presume this is inefficient (because it's doing a replacement), but I haven't actually performance tested it...

StringTokenizer deals correctly with unicode characters, so you can also do something like this:

```
public static boolean isOneChar(String string) {
    String firstChar = string.substring(0, string.offsetByCodePoints(0, 1));
    return new StringTokenizer(string, firstChar).countTokens() == 0;
}
```

Again, there's not really any need to go all the way through the string, so I assume that this isn't as efficient as the regex solution.

Comment: Thanks. It hadn't really occurred to me before writing this answer that most java code that uses chartAt, length or the char primitive is probably wrong.